# Is there a better way to split up details from a directory listing in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to convert a file listing into structured data. 
This is a standard file listing from windows as per below.

Currently im splitting this up using spaces. 
First replacing multiple spaces into a single space then splitting on space. But i feel like this can be better done (or assume it can be better done) with regex and matching/grouping?

My current code looks like this.

```
def extract_columns_from_file_name(text, curr_dir, mappedProductNames):    

text = re.sub('\s+',' ',text)
space_location = text.find(" ")
date = text[0:space_location]
text = text[space_location+1:len(text)]

space_location = text.find(" ")
timeA = text[0:space_location]
text = text[space_location+1:len(text)]

space_location = text.find(" ")
timeB = text[0:space_location]
text = text[space_location+1:len(text)]

time = timeA + " " + timeB

space_location = text.find(" ")
size = text[0:space_location]
size = re.sub(',','',size)
text = text[space_location+1:len(text)]
```

The text i am converting looks like this.

```
28/11/2019  05:26 PM     2,074,273,364 jdev_suite_122130_win64.exe
```

Comment: Is your solution deficient in some way?

Comment: Have you tried `text.split()`?

Comment: [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will split on (consecutive) whitespace .

Comment: splitting based on spaces feels like an easy way out.. I was thinking there must be a way to match each type into a group and use regex to split it all up

Comment: Your could use `"28/11/2019 05:26 PM 2,074,273,364 jdev_suite_122130_win64.exe".split(/ +(? *!AM|PM)/)`. The regular expression matches one or more spaces that are not followed by 'AM' or 'PM'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by regex like this:

```
import re

text = "28/11/2019  05:26 PM     2,074,273,364 jdev_suite_122130_win64.exe"

m = re.match(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+) +(\d{2}:\d{2} (?:AM|PM)) +([0-9,]+) ([\w.]+)', text)
if m:
    print(m.groups())
```

Output:

```
('28/11/2019', '05:26 PM', '2,074,273,364', 'jdev_suite_122130_win64.exe')
```

Comment: I question the value of the checks on the field formats, as it would happily pass `'99/99/9999  99:99 PM , .'`.  One could make those parts of the regex more complex (which still wouldn't catch `'29/02/2100'`). If those fields need to be checked wouldn't it be better to just have the regex divide the string into four fields, on the assumption that they are correct values, and then test each field separately, as needed? It would be especially easy to test if the date and time were valid and if the third field is the string representation of an integer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree one could make the checking of dates and times more complicated. However, I don't think that was implicit in the question. The main task was to split the line into groups. The regex I provided will cover the general case assuming the input is correct.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks both. Thats correct i have no need to check the date format at present. Just that i need to be able to split it all up into groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use split that will split based on space and will return you a list with all the fields

```
fields = text.split()
print (fields)
```

The output will be & you can use it as you want

```
['28/11/2019', '05:26', 'PM', '2,074,273,364', 'jdev_suite_122130_win64.exe']
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the simple way around it, but was wondering if there is a way to do this via regex matching into groups.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#csv-text-files) for better manipulation of data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=' ', header=None)
```

Comment: You should have (and explain) a good reason for introducing a heavy dependency like pandas to solve a tiny problem.

Comment: It appears that this would split `'05:26 PM'` on the space, which is not wanted.